# How to check different mysql tables and get output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have retrieved following data from `allbook` table,

```
Book Name   copies
Book1         5
Book2         6
Book3         7
Book4         8
```

Further I have another table,`issuedbooks` which I issued those books to some students.

```
Student   BookName      Issued Date
Ann         Book1        5/20/2022
Mike        Book1        5/21/2022
Micheal     Book2        5/22/2022
John        Book3        5/23/2022
```

Now I need to consider both two tables and get the availability at the moment as below.

```
BookName    AvailableCopies
Book1            3
Book2            5
Book3            6
Book4            8
```

Are there any method to retrieve it from mysql query? can someone show me how to combine both above tables?

Comment: You know that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM issuedbooks WHERE BookName='Book1';` will give you the outstanding count, right?  From there, it should be pretty easy.

Comment: I think in order for this to work you would need another column in the 2nd table that would state if the book had been returned or not. Otherwise you wouldn't know if the book was back in inventory or not. Unless it was a table that was only populated with books that were currently checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use subquery get all count from `issuedbooks` then do `OUTER JOIN` base on `allbook` which will keep `BookName` if only exists from `allbook`

```
SELECT ab.BookName,
       ab.copies - coalesce(ib.cnt,0) AvailableCopies
FROM allbook ab
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BookName,COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM issuedbooks
    GROUP BY BookName
) ib
ON ab.BookName = ib.BookName
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ee7055a7c34b7890beebdc1b831d2154)